# How to use a backward search using Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to make a search for several parameters. In input string i can have fields: type and number.

Field number is a number like(3,2.15, 11.64).
Type field is a string like "com", "org", "cu", "mi"

```
Possible variations of input string:
```

3 mi

2 com

3,13--org

i would like to find some strings matching this string.
So, i have to make some

```
select number, type from orders
where (%number%) like '49-М' or (%type%) like '49-М'
```

But it doesn't work. How can i compare exactly fields?

And also i can't split string into 2 numbers, cause i don't know a separator

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but `regexp_substr()` should be able to help:

```
where (%number%) like regexp_substr('49-M', '^[0-9.]+', 1) and
      (%type%) like regexp_substr('49-M', '[a-zA-Z]+$', 1)
```